# Quais diferenças entre um programador PL/SQL e um DBA Oracle?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, oracle, pl-sql

Alguém poderia me explicar as diferenças entre o programador *PL/SQL* e o *DBA Oracle*? Sei que há muitas diferenças, porém não sei ao certo como especificá-las.

Tenho algumas dúvidas também...

Por exemplo:

> Um *DBA* pode programar `Procedures`?

A carreira do programador *PL/SQL* pode se expandir para *DBA*?

Comment: Defina o que é DBA Oracle? Pode estar me escapando alguma coisa, mas a pergunta parece não fazer sentido.

Comment: Leia isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5487/132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que são especializações diferentes dentro da vertente de Banco de Dados na informática, mas complementares.

Como eu trabalho em Fábrica de Software, cada projeto o foco é um: as vezes programação SQL (PL-SQL), as vezes é um papel mais de "AD" (que realiza a modelagem dos dados), outro momento visa Administração de SGBD.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, @Melanie!
Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: De nada, @EduardoR :)

Answer (score 3):

Em termos simples:

---

**DBA (*Database Administrator*)**

É a pessoa (ou equipe) responsável por administrar o banco de dados.
Algumas de suas principais responsabilidades são:

- Garantir a performance do banco;
- Garantir que os acessos/permissões estão corretos;
- Garantir que os dados estejam disponíveis e acessíveis;
- Identificar e resolver problemas no banco e de performance;
- Identificar e reportar execução de queries lentas e que consomem muito processamento e/ou memória;

**PL/SQL (Procedural Language/Structured Query Language) Programmer**

É qualquer pessoa (ou equipe) que escreve *procedures*, *functions*, *packages*, e *queries*.

Essa atividade não é de exclusividade de um DBA.
Na verdade, normalmente, DBAs não criam consultas nem *procedures*. Isso fica sob responsabilidade dos "Programadores de PL/SQL" propriamente ditos.

É comum que um programador de qualquer linguagem como Java, C#, VB e etc saiba escrever *procedures* e *queries*.
O DBA, por sua vez, auxiliá-os com o que for necessário ao que diz respeito ao banco.